# How to fix “iptables: No chain/target/match by that name”?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, iptables

I built and installed iptables on my linux embedded system. If I list all rules, everything works fine:

```
#iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

But, if I add a new rule to block icmp ping, I'll get the follwing error:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p icmp --icmp-type any -s 0/0 -d 10.20.3.179 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j DROP
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chain and target look correct, so it must be the match. Make sure CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATE is enabled in your kernel config.

Comment: sorry, but I haven't it in .config, I have CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_COMMENT, *MATCH_DCCP,*MATCH_DSCP and others. My kernel is 2.6.31-rc9

Comment: It depends on NF_CONNTRACK: From net/netfilter/Kconfig:

config NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATE
        tristate '"state" match support'
        depends on NF_CONNTRACK
        default m if NETFILTER_ADVANCED=n

Comment: I'm glad you've got the solution for your problem, but I have the same issue and this doesn't really give me much confidence here. I need to fix this on a production server.