# iptables does not recognize the --dport argument

Tags: iptables, yocto

I'm trying to set some iptables rules on a Linux Yocto device but this command  keeps giving me an error:

```
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j MYCHAIN

iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

The problematic argument is "--dport" as the following command works perfectly:

```
# iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -j MYCHAIN
```

Researching, I have found similar problems ([match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679749/how-to-fix-iptables-no-chain-target-match-by-that-name), [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274337/iptables-error-iptables-no-chain-target-match-by-that-name)) related with missing kernel modules. If this is my case, how can I know which one it is?

Comment: I couldn't find proper missing kernel module needed for this case but please look at this question - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36188472/yocto-adding-kernel-module-recipe-to-image-but-it-doesnt-load-on-boot) there is describe how in Yocto build and apply kernel modules with using [module.bbclass](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#ref-classes-module).

Comment: I have no access to the build tools. The software is provided by a third party. I will perform a request to them but I would like to specify the module needed to speed up the request if possible.